# SoftDeletes и полиморфная связь в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Существует сущность Activity, и она связана с другими полиморфной связью. В сущности Acitivity включено мягкое удаление, и существует поле 'deleted_at'. В связанных сущностях нет такого поля.

```
use SoftDeletes;
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

Появляется из-за этого ошибка, что начинает искать поле 'deleted_at' в связанных сущностях, и выводит ошибку

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'mails.deleted_at' in 'where clause'

Как можно сделать, чтобы deleted_at брался только у Activity, а связанные не смотрели на это.

P.S У связанных сущностей не включено мягкое удаление

**UPD:**

**Activity.php**

```
class Activity extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $connection = 'mysql';

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function activityable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

**Mail.php**

```
class Mail extends Activity
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql';

    protected $guarded = [];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function activity(){
        return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Crm\Activity', 'activityable');
    }
}
```

AcitivityController.php

```
class ActivityController extends Controller
{
    public function edit($id)
    {
      $activity = Activity::select('activities.name', 'activities.status', 'activities.description', 'activities.meet_id', 'activities.activityable_id', 'activities.activityable_type', 'activities.created_at')
            ->with('activityable')
            ->where('activities.id', $id)
            ->first();
    }
}
```

Comment: Чет не пойму ты софт кому дал ? должен был дать только Activity, тогда остальные смотреть никуда не будут.

Comment: @Orange_shadow Только Activity и дал

Comment: приведи пример: моделей и контроллера где используешь

Comment: @Orange_shadow, обновил

Comment: Ну так ты ж наследуешь от Activity вот он и ругается `class Mail extends Activity` сделай `class Mail extends Model`

Comment: @Orange_shadow, Спасибо, не заметил) Ответьте на вопрос, я правильным его зачту

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо убрать наследование от класса `Activity` в классе `Mail` и поставить `extends Model`